# Possible to have more than 2 values in equality checks? (> NUM1 NUM2) ELISP

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

The function "greaterthan", `(< NUM1 NUM2)`, allows only for returning t/nil for comparing 2 values.

I would like to test (var1 > var2 < var3 < var4), is there any way to do that using only one function in lisp? If not, what is the best procedure?

Answer (score 6):

The best procedure is not to bother: `(and (< var2 var1) (< var2 var3) (< var3 var4))` is not harder to read that your `..>..<..<..` chain.

It makes sense to test for the ascending order:

```
(require 'cl)
(defun cl-< (&rest args)
   (every '< args (cdr args))
```

These days I don't hesitate to `(require 'cl)` anymore, but if you do,
here is another variant:

```
(defun cl-< (arg &rest more-args)
  (or (null more-args)
      (and (< arg (first more-args))
           (apply #'cl-< more-args))))
```

Comment: Yea I figured that it could be done in 3 steps. Still, imagine having to do several similar tests, such as (var1 < var2 > var 3 < var 4), I think it would be easier to read if it could be done that way.

Comment: This is excellent though! It is even possible to test an uneven amount of arguments here. Is there no way to do this without requiring `cl`?

Comment: Added a variant which does not require `cl`. Generally, writing without `cl` is much harder, and what we're doing here is adding a Common Lispish `<` function anyway (it would be a *part* of `cl.el` if a bit more people needed it).

Answer (score 2):

The following is a macro implementation for variadic `<`

```
(defmacro << (x y &rest args)
  (if args
      (if (or (symbolp y)
              (numberp y))
          `(and (< ,x ,y) (<< ,y ,@args))
          (let ((ys (make-symbol "y")))
            `(let (,ys)
               (and (< ,x (setq ,ys ,y))
                    (<< ,ys ,@args)))))
      `(< ,x ,y)))
```

for simple cases just expands to `(and ...)` chains

```
(<< x y z) ==> (and (< x y) (< y z))
```

where the expression is not a number and not a symbol expands to a more complex form to avoid multiple evaluations in presence of side effects

```
(<< (f x) (g y) (h z)) ==> (let ((gy)) (and (< (f x) (setq gy (g y)))
                                            (< gy (h z))))
```

for example

```
(setq foo (list))
nil

(defun call (x) (push x foo) x)
call

(<< (call 1) (call 2) (call 5) (call 4) (call 0))
nil

foo
(4 5 2 1)
```

every function has been called once, except for `0` that didn't need to be called because of short circuiting (I'm not 100% sure if short circuiting is a really good idea or not... `#'<` in Common Lisp is a regular function with all arguments all evaluated exactly once in left-to-right order without short circuiting).

Comment: @wvxvw: note that in Common Lisp `#'<` is a regular function so all arguments are always evaluated exactly once in left-to-right order. Originally I liked the idea of short-circuiting (like Python does for example does `f() <= g() < h()`) but later found that in practice multiple-arguments/single-operator tests are not that useful (what is nice in Python is that you can have different operators and a semi-open interval check is IMO a very common case, something that would require irregular syntax). `=` and `/=` case however seems useful (with `/=` checking all pairs short-circuiting).

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun << (arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4)
 (when (and (< arg1 arg2) (< arg2 arg3) (< arg3 arg4)))
)

(<< 1 2 3 4)
```

Probably possible to extend with any amount of arguments, but such a general form would seem useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defmacro << (&rest args)
  (let ((first (car args))
        (min (gensym))
        (max (gensym))
        (forms '(t)) iterator)
    (setq args (reverse (cdr args))
          iterator args)
    `(let ((,min ,first) ,max)
       ,(or 
         (while iterator
           (push `(setq ,min ,max) forms)
           (push  `(< ,min ,max) forms)
           (push `(setq ,max ,(car iterator)) forms)
           (setq iterator (cdr iterator))) `(and ,@forms)))))

(macroexpand '(<< 10 20 30 (+ 30 3) (* 10 4)))
(let ((G99730 10) G99731)
  (and (setq G99731 20)
       (< G99730 G99731)
       (setq G99730 G99731)
       (setq G99731 30)
       (< G99730 G99731)
       (setq G99730 G99731)
       (setq G99731 (+ 30 3))
       (< G99730 G99731)
       (setq G99730 G99731)
       (setq G99731 (* 10 4))
       (< G99730 G99731)
       (setq G99730 G99731) t))
```

This is the idea similar to 6502's, but it may create less code, in a less trivial situation, but it will create more code in a trivial situation.